# Is there a service to mirror a web site to another computer?

Tags: web-browser, web

We have a video wall with some monitors. each one is plugged into a Raspberry PI. Mostly we just are showing webpages into the video wall (reports, status etc)

Today we control the content of each raspberry using VNC.

I was wondering if is there a web service or plugin that allows me to just send the URL that i wish to son screen. Plus, Sometimes we split the each screen into 2 or more webpages.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the command `ssh user@some-raspberry-pi firefox 'http://the-website-you-want-to-show.example'` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you want is a better OS that is purpose built for what you want to do.

Check out https://www.screenly.io/

If you still feel that you need to mirror a website, you can use `wget` with some options (which needed depend on what kind of mirror you want, etc)